# where can find VoxCeleb2 dataset? the origin website's dataset are no longer available

Tags: deep-learning, dataset

where can find VoxCeleb2 dataset? the origin website's dataset are no longer available

can you give me a link-site that can get voxceleb2 dataset.I really need that.